# Git push error: "! [rejected] develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)"

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a list of commits (newest first):

```
abcd4 message
abcd3 wrong commit message2
abcd2 wrong commit message1
abcd1 message
```

I need to change commit messages of `abcd2` and `abcd3`.
I'm doing it the following way:

```
rebase -i abcd1
```

Then, in interactive mode I replace `pick` with `reword`,
change the necessary commit messages and save the changes. Everything works fine here.

The problem is the following: the branch is fully pushed to Bitbucket so there are wrong commit messages on Bitbucket as well.

I tried to push the changes but got the error:

```
 ! [rejected]        develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://login@bitbucket.org/user/repository.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I tried to pull the changes but got smth. weird after pull was accomplished:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h %s' --graph
*   ccceeefff Merge branch 'develop' of https://bitbucket.org/user/repository into develop
|\  
| * abcd3 wrong commit message2
| * abcd2 wrong commit message1
* | new_hash_of_abcd3 new commit message2
* | new_hash_of_abcd2 new commit message1
|/  
* abcd1 message
```

So my question is: what is the correct way to change the messages in my case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to force the push with (assuming you have bitbucket set up as the remote "origin"):

```
git checkout develop
git push -f origin develop
```

Note that before you do that you may need to reset your local develop branch (if it's now pointing at your pulled/merged commit):

```
git checkout develop
git reset --hard new_hash_of_abcd3
git push -f origin develop
```